# document.getElementById().innerHTML not getting text in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I rendered the date via a function called `renderToday()`. The reason I want to get the date, is so I can go left, or right from that date. And I need to change the date accordingly.

```
renderToday: function() {
    var today = new Date();
    return today.toDateString();
  },
```

I tried using `document.getElementById('date')`, and I set the `div` with an id of "date", and I used `.innerHTML`. Now everything below AccountsUIWrapper, doesn't show up now.

```
renderMoods() {
    // Get tasks from this.data.moods
    var d = document.getElementById("date");
    return (<div>{d.innerHTML}</div>);
},

render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>How are You?</h1>
        <AccountsUIWrapper />

        { this.data.currentUser ?
        <div>
        <form className="your_mood" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <select ref="mood">
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Select your Mood</option>
            <option value=":)">:)</option>
            <option value=":|">:|</option> 
            <option value=":(">:(</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>

        </form> 

        <div id="date">
          {this.renderToday()}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.renderMoods()}
        </div>
        </div>
        : '' 
      }

      </div>
    );
  }
 });
```

Comment: *`document.GetElementById()`  typo `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @rajuGT man! read the code, not the title! The title of this post is very wrong, but the code not

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: How would you improve the title? Because i tried fixing the getelementbyid, and it didn't do anything

Comment: @taxicala I don't get any error in terminal(node).

Comment: Why don't you save the result of `renderToday` as a state and use it in `renderMoods`?

Comment: @taggon I don't know how to do it! I'll check it ou

Comment: What is `<AccountsUIWrapper />`? You say everything below that won't show, so remove that to isolate your problem.

Comment: I've removed my answer because someone thinks that it is not useful - I've added it there https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/1fLk7n8g/

Comment: @Alexander code in your fiddle looks fine to me: with answer + explanation why original code does not work. So upvote on your comment, and would have upvoted on your answer too. (Which I just did)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude  I didn't say that is the actual issue or whatever. I just said correct that alphabet case. I believe title also has as importance as question body. So I just mentioned it, and it is corrected now by someone's edit.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are trying get element from `DOM` in time when `DOM` is not ready, you can just call `renderToday()` in `renderMoods()`

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    renderToday() {
        return Date.now();
    },

    renderMoods() {
        return <h2>
            { this.renderToday() }
        </h2>;
    },

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Component</h1>
            <div>{ this.renderToday() }</div>
            <div>{ this.renderMoods() }</div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/19945/)

you can call `DOM` operations in `componentDidMount` handler, read more about [`component lifecycle`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) - *it is possible but not recommended*

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    renderToday() {
        return Date.now();
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        document.getElementById('mood').innerHTML = document.getElementById('date').innerHTML
    },

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Component</h1>
            <div id="date">{ this.renderToday() }</div>
            <div id="mood"></div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/19946/)